# Question about data storage after deletion of app

Tags: applications

I am using Android 6.0.1 though i'm not sure that would make a difference with my question. So my question is after an app has been uninstalled through Settings --> Apps and then clicking the "Uninstall" button after selecting the particular app is there, in general, any evidence left on the phone that the app was ever installed? Secondly, if so how can that evidence be removed? Sort of like how a browser has a "browser history" after you've visited sites is there anything analogous in a history or a cache of some sort that can be recovered to see that the app was once on the phone and OS (barring a sophisticated forensic analysis). If i were to hand the phone to someone who is tech savvy or knows their way around android would they be able to ascertain that the app was once there?

Comment: If the app has permission to access the storage, yes, there are possibilities that there maybe residues left by the app, even after uninstallation. Other than that, uninstalling an app removes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, **any kind** of data erased from a memory can be recovered since the *space is "marked" as empty so new datas can be overwritten over them*.
Those datas can be easily recovered with software like **Recuva** or more advanced forensic tools. *You need to overwrite them with a third-party software*.

On Android this can be achieved with apps like [Secure Eraser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aiuspaktyn.secureeraser). (
*This kind of applications can not guarantee 100% that the data have been permanently erased*)

Also remember that a list of the applications downloaded from **Google Play** is available on GPlay app under the **App > My Apps** tab. You can also see them from a web browser on [this](https://play.google.com/apps) page after logging-in to your **Google Account**.